# Error Code 400002: The category parameter is invalid using Azure Custom Translation API

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I am utilizing the Custom Translation API with POST endpoint: `https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/translate`

The full query url with Category ID obfuscated is: `https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/translate?api-version=3.0&category=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx-GENERAL&from=en&to=fr&includeSentenceLength=true`

This query works without the category parameter but fails with the following response when it is included:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400002,
    "message": "The category parameter is invalid."
  }
}
```

I have added the Subscription Key into the Custom Translation Portal. Not sure why this request fails.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out I'm an idiot. Even with a simple Dictionary as I had in this case, one must still train and deploy a model with that dictionary.

Comment: No sir, Microsoft is an idiot. The error messages returned does not make sense! Category is valid and we copied it from the portal. I am deploying now and will retry but MS can help by providing better error messages